# Отобразить MAC на сайте

Tags: c#, asp.net

Как можно отобразить MAC-адрес в `Lable` компьютера пользователя при переходе на сайт написанный на aspx?

Comment: MAC-адрес _чего_? Если вы имеете в виду сетевого интерфейса на клиенте, то учтите, что C#-код бежит на сервере, а HTML-коду доступ к аппаратуре браузер не даст.

Comment: И `Label` или какой-то другой контейнер текста — наименьшая из проблем.

Comment: это возможно только при заходе через lan (когда можно вытащить mac по ip)

Comment: Ну IP я знаю как получить Label1.Text = Request.UserHostAddress; но мне ещё нужно узнать MAC адрес lan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MAC (Media Access Control)-адрес - можно узнать только если машина клиента физически включена в ту же сеть, без каких-либо прокси или маршрутизаторов по дороге. Media - это физическая среда, грубо говоря, провод (возможно, удлиненный с помощью повторителей/коммутаторов).

Получение IP адреса:

```
string ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Получение MAC по IP - вызовом нативного метода:

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern int SendARP( int destIp, int srcIP, byte[] macAddr, ref uint physicalAddrLen );
```

Пример с [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/SendARP.html):

```
IPAddress dst = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress); // the destination IP address

byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

if (SendARP(BitConverter.ToInt32(dst.GetAddressBytes(), 0), 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) != 0)
     throw new InvalidOperationException("SendARP failed.");

string[] str = new string[(int)macAddrLen];
for (int i=0; i<macAddrLen; i++)
     str[i] = macAddr[i].ToString("x2");

string mac = string.Join(":", str);
```

Comment: Угу, а если юзер за корпоративным прокси?

Comment: Если я правильно понял мы этот код запиливаем в aspx.cs так?

Comment: к стати  VladD прав у нас корпоративная прокся.

Comment: @VladD я еще в комменте к вопросу написал "возможно только при заходе через lan (когда можно вытащить mac по ip)".

Comment: @Павел mac-адрес можно узнать только если машина клиента физически включена в ту же сеть. просто потому, что это media access control address. media - это физическая среда, грубо говоря, провод.

Comment: @PashaPash: Угу, я уже видел. Возможно, имеет смысл дописать это в ответ, т. к. это важная информация.

Comment: @VladD дописал.

Comment: У нас одна сеть с разными VLAN'ами. Вопрос куда этот код вписать что бы проверить?

Comment: да работает только в одном VLAN'е в других не работает. Большое спасибо за помощь в поиске решения.